# I can't make this promise work

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use Promises instead of Callback in my Lambda Function in NodeJs 4.3.  What I'm trying to do is read a config file from S3 and use the configuration to connect to a DB and execute a SELECT statement on a table. When I test the function, I don't get any errors in the console.

I have defined my function as follows:

```
function setUpConnection(response) {
console.log("S3 Response " +  JSON.stringify(response));
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    config = response.Body.toString('utf-8');
    config = JSON.parse( config );
    // set up connection from S3 config file
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.hostaddress,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.pass,
      database: config.dbname
    });
    console.log("connection " +  JSON.stringify(con));
    console.log("config " +  JSON.stringify(config));
    // create connection
    con.connect(function(err){
      if(err){
        // Output connection details for debugging
        console.log('Error connecting to DB');
        return Promise.reject(new Error(output));
      }
    });
    // Run Select Query
    con.query("SELECT * FROM goodsreceiptheader WHERE invoiceKey = ?", [invoicekey], function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            con.end();
            return Promise.reject(new Error(output));
        }
        if ( res.length <= 0  ){
            console.log('Response Object ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            con.end();
            return Promise.reject(new Error(output));
        }
        resolve(res);
    })
})
```

}

The function is being called by this function:

```
// Setup goodsreceipt info
var goodsreceipt = data.goodsreceipt;

getObjectPromise = s3bucket.getObject(params).promise()
getObjectPromise
.then(setUpConnection)
.then(validateRecord)
.catch(callback(null, Error))
```

When I execute this code, I am only seeing the result of the code

```
console.log("S3 Response " +  JSON.stringify(response));
```

on the second line.  Is there a problem with the way I configured setUpConnection?

Comment: But you've made a promise, and now you must keep it...

Comment: first of all you need to move code "con.query..." inside con.connect - because it is async function;
second: .catch(callback(null, Error)) -> .catch(function(err) {console.error(err)})

Comment: thanks.  This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're using rejection in a wrong way.

```
return Promise.reject(new Error(output));
```

Should be replaced with

```
reject(new Error(output));
return;
```

Also catch call looks strange: it calls callback immediately. Usually catch block looks like that:

```
somePromise.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error); // If output required.
    callback(error); // If callback provided.
});
```

Move con.query call inside of con.connect callback.

Comment: reject(new Error(output));
return;

Comment: but I got the same error.  The catch statement shouldn't cause a problem right?

Comment: I am a bit confused.  If the problem is in the position of the connect query, shouldn't I  able to see the result of the console.log for config and connection?  At the moment, I am not seeing those.  By the way, I am doing this inside AWS lambda.  Not sure if it has any effect on the promise

Comment: Position is important because it breaks call order. Thus real error could not be produced. After all there is no any output into mysql.conn call but error rejecting only, thus we don't know if it works properly.

Comment: ok, although the code still didn't work when I updated the position of the select query.  what made it work was the suggestion to change the catch function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from where output is coming? I don't see it anywhere defined.
Second of all it is considered as good practice to always throw/reject with an instance of `Error`, in your example i guess, at least by variable name, `output` is not an instance of `Error`. Third thing in general only valid use case in my opinion of using `new Promise` constructor is when you want to transform callback api to promise which you are doing here (which is good) or you when deal with `setTimeout/setInterval`

Anyway you are using `Promise.reject` where you have `reject` in scope already which is not how you should reject your promise in this case. Next thing is that you are using `con.query` outside of callback that is provided to `con.connect` which effectively means you are calling `query` before connection was successfully established, try with something like:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ...
  con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
      return reject(new Error('...'));
    }

    // Run Select Query
    con.query(..., ..., function (err,res) {
      if(err){
        ...
        return reject(new Error('...'));
      }

      if (res.length <= 0 ){
        ...
        return reject(new Error(output));
      }

      return resolve(res);
    })
  });
})
```

Few sides notes:
 1. Check does this lib have promise api, probably it should in that way you dont need to promisify things around on your own.
 2. If it doesnt have you can always use libs like `bluebird` to promisfy code for you

Comment: i just removed the output variable in the post to reduce the number of lines but there are lines of codes that initializes the value for the output.  I guess what confuses me is that when I run the code, I don't see any error message in the console even though I do have some lines that executes console.log .  Also, I was under the impression that Promise is already part of Nodejs core so I didn't use the other libraries such as bluebird.

Comment: native Promises are supported by node but that doesnt mean that you will take advantage of it if you are using librabry with callback based api

Comment: you mean, moving the con.query inside con.connect?  Yup, but I still got the same problem.  My function just completes without sending any ,message to the console after the first console.log

Answer (score 0):

You rejection of promise is wrong

Try in this way

```
function setUpConnection(response) {

console.log("S3 Response " +  JSON.stringify(response));
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    config = response.Body.toString('utf-8');
    config = JSON.parse( config );
    // set up connection from S3 config file
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.hostaddress,
        user: config.user,
        password: config.pass,
        database: config.dbname
    });
    console.log("connection " +  JSON.stringify(con));
    console.log("config " +  JSON.stringify(config));
    // create connection
    con.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            // Output connection details for debugging
            console.log('Error connecting to DB');
            return reject(err);
        }
    });
    // Run Select Query
    con.query("SELECT * FROM goodsreceiptheader WHERE invoiceKey = ?", [invoicekey], function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            con.end();
            return reject(err);
        }
        if ( res.length <= 0  ){
            console.log('Response Object ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            con.end();
            return reject('response less 0');
        }
        resolve(res);
    })
})
}
```

Comment: looks like my problem was in the catch statement